# How go I go about using a variable value with while loops in python?

Tags: python, loops

In my program, the input from my temperature sensor is a float. The temperature sensor reads the temperature every one second. How do I set off functions when for example, the value is above or below 29?

Here's what I've Tried:

```
condition = float(29.0)
while temp_c > 29:
        GPIO.output(24,GPIO.high)

 while temp_c < 29:
        GPIO.output(24,GPIO.low)
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

Make a while loop for your whole program. For example, an infinite one like:

```
while 1 == 1:
```

Then indent the rest of your code, and somewhere in your code say:

```
if temperature > 29:
    GPIO.output(24,GPIO.high)

elif temperature < 29:
    GPIO.output(24,GPIO.low)
```

Hope this helped! If it didn't let me know so that I can try something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two while loops, one with the condition value<29 and the other value>=29 all inside a while(1) loop. There is probably a better way, but that should work.